# Как передать список в аргумент функции Python

Tags: python, функции, список

Здрвствуйте , есть код:

```
num = [33,34,35,36,50]
num_my = [33,36,50]
num_res = []

'''Цикл проверяет повторяеться ли цифра 'num' в 'num_my' если да то добовляет в список num_res[]'''

for number in num:
    if number in num_my:
        num_res.append(number)

print(num_res)
```

как мне сделать чтобы функции список(num_my) передавался через аргумент?
что я делаю не так? нужно чтобы функция отрабатывала как пример выше.

```
def result(num_my):

    num = [54,24,34,1,2,3]
    num_res = []

    for number in num:
        if number in num_my:
            num_res.append(number)
        return num_res

num_1 = (result([54,24,1,2,3]))
num_2 = (result([34,1,3]))

print(num_1)
print(num_2)
```

Comment: Сейчас что не так? Сдвинь return на уровень влево.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно убрать один отступ в функции, чтобы стало так:

```
def result(num_my):

    num = [54,24,34,1,2,3]
    num_res = []

    for number in num:
        if number in num_my:
            num_res.append(number)
    return num_res
```

А еще лучше, если вы используете "pythonicway":

```
def result(num_my):
    num = [54,24,34,1,2,3]
    return [number for number in num if number in num_my]
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо, все моя не внимательность((
просидел час точно думал что не так делаю, а тут такая мелочь)))))
Спасибо за подсказку!)